# BeautifulSoup: Extract content of html-element with double quotation marks in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the content of an element from a website with BeautifulSoup. Here is what the typical relevant html-code looks like:

```
<html>
<script for="document" event="onkeypress()" language="JScript"
type="text/jscript">
<!--
{
  if(window.event.shiftKey)
    javascript:window.print();
}
//-->
</script>

<head>

<title>Some title here</title>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta NAME="Generator" CONTENT="Some content here">
<meta NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOARCHIVE">
<meta NAME="keywords" CONTENT=
"This is the important content~It is seperated by tilde~Information~Information"
>
<meta NAME="Ddate" CONTENT="">
<meta NAME="Makz" CONTENT="67">
```

In most of the cases, it works perfectly fine with the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(fid, 'html')

important_infos = soup.find("meta", {"name":"keywords"})["content"]
splitted_infos = important_infos.split('~')
```

But in some cases, the information I need has extra quotation marks and BeautifulSoup only catches the content until the second quotation mark occurs and simply stops then. So the element I am looking for looks lik this for example:

```
<meta NAME="keywords" CONTENT="Info1~Info2~Company with an "Example Name"~Info4~Info5">
```

So I only get the contet until "wth an " and all the other infos are not included.

Is there a way to solve this problem and still catch all the infos from CONTENT even with those double quotation marks?

Comment: i dont get why it converted in to this `<meta content="Info1~Info2~Company with an " example="" name="keywords" name"~info4~info5"=""/>
`

Comment: ya that's interesting. I'm wondering if you'll just have to convert the whole element to a string and then use regex to pull it out.

Comment: Yes it's just like you said, if you read the page into BeautifulSoup the way I described above, it transforms the element to the element @BhavyaParikh posted. So it's not possible to transform it into string and then use regex because the infos get already lost while opening the file with BeautiflSoup. So any other ideas guys?